# triggering a function in component in Ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

When i'm transiting to my new route, i set reportName property and i want based on observing reportname change postobject and trigger sending ajax request. on the response of ajax i get data which i want to pass to my graph component as a property and this updated property with data value cause a function in my component to be triggered. But im not able to do so. Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong. I am new with ember. 
Pod Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
    sessionService: Ember.inject.service('session'),

    nameOfReport: null,  

    postObject: function(){
        return {
            Name: this.get('nameOfReport'),
            Take: 30,
            Skip: 0,
        };
    }.property('nameOfReport'),


    ajaxResponse: function(){

       var restApiHost = serverPath + '/report';
       var postobj=  this.get('postObject');
       var token =this.get('sessionService.session.authenticated.access_token');

        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: restApiHost,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(postobj),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var bearer = 'Bearer ' + token ;
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', bearer);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var graphobj= {
                    data:  data.data,          
                    graphModel: GraphModel.create({
                        graphHeight: "320",
                        graphMargin: [40, 80, 40, 60],
                        xDomain: [1, 10],
                        yDomain: [1, 100]
                    …
                    })};
                 Ember.set(this,'graphobject', graphobj);    
            },

            fail: function () {
                alert('Could not contact server');
            },
        });
    }.property('postObject'),       


    graphobject: function(){
        this.get('ajaxResponse');
    }.property('ajaxResponse'),

});
```

Pod Template:

```
<div>
               {{line-graph model= graphobject }} 
</div>
```

Component:

```
drawGraph: function() {
        // define dimensions of graph   
        var graphdata = this.get('model.data');
        var graphmodel = this.get('model.graphModel');
...
}.property('graphobject'),
```

Comment: Have you considered the asynchronous  behaviour of your `ajaxResponse` method?

Comment: behavior of Ajax response was my main concern. What i am looking for is to draw my graph component with the data i get back from Ajax request

Answer (score 3):

First, your line `Ember.set(this,'graphobject', graphobj);` actually overwrites the function you store in the `graphobject` property -- so you don't need that function.

Second, even if your `drawGraph` property is marked dirty because one of its dependent keys have changed (which appears to be the case in your code), it isn't run until some code `get`s the property.  That could happen during a re-render if the template itself accesses the property, or otherwise from an observer or when an action is run.

Try making `drawGraph` observe `graphobject`.  Additionally, you may need to run `drawGraph` on initialization or insertion:

```
drawGraph: function() {
    // define dimensions of graph
    var graphdata = this.get('model.data');
    var graphmodel = this.get('model.graphModel');
    ...
}.observes('graphobject').on('init')/* or .on('didInsertElement') */,
```

Most people recommend avoiding observers, but since I don't know what you're doing in the `drawGraph` function, it's hard to recommend something else in general.

If you are setting a property in `drawGraph` and then rendering that property in a template, then you could make `drawGraph` return that value (instead of setting it into the other property), and render `drawGraph` in the template instead of the other property.  (Don't make `drawGraph` an observe then; keep it as a computed property.)

If you're doing jQuery to manipulate the DOM inside `drawGraph`, and can't do that with templates for some reason, then the observer may be the only way to go.

Actually, looking at your code more, I see that `ajaxResponse` should also be an observer too.  However, again you want to avoid observers, so I'd ask myself, when should I make an AJAX request and re-render the graph?  I don't think the answer will be whenever the report name changes.  It's probably more like when a user clicks a button like "save" or "view" or something, in which case, that button should send an action somewhere, and that action should then trigger the AJAX call and then the re-render of the graph.  But, it depends on your app.